# Delete line from text file

Tags: serial, sd

In order to make an algorithm work, I'd like to delete the first line of a text file. I'm having a hard time finding an example for that though. I was thinking that there should be the possibility to delete up to a \n. Could you point me to a solution?
Oh, I'm using a standard Arduino Uno

Thank you

Comment: Is it necessary to re-write the file, or is this a file whose later contents will be read and processed by the Arduino? If the latter, then you can just read and throw away a character at a time until you get to `'\n'` after you open the file.

Comment: Well, in this case, the Arduino is connected to Wifi and serves each produced data point as a .csv to a server. I suppose this counts as "processing by Arduino". 
So what you suggest would work. I'm not sure though how one would go about to "throw away a character". Is there a search term for that, so I can check it out? Thanks!

Comment: To read the file, you would use `fopen()` to open it and get a file handle. Then you use `fgetc()` to read one character at a time and check that character to see if it's `'\n'`. By "throwing away", I mean that the character you read can just be overwritten by the next one you read -- you don't have to build a string or anything or try to save the character for later in the program.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

- opening a file (to read)
- opening a new file (to write)
- since a line can be long (more than arduino's memory), it's best to read it character by character, thus:
- use a boolean to denote when to start removing a line (set to e.g. Remove = TRUE)
- For every character you read:

  - If Remove is TRUE, don't write to the output file, otherwise write it
  - If the character is \n or \r (check how line ends are), set the boolean to False (e.g. continue writing)
- Remove file to read
- Rename written file